# run eval isolated when taking a string from the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm storing this code in my DB:

```
def is_ten?(number)
  number == 10 
end

is_ten?(10)
```

now I reference this from a class method that belongs to the model that stores it.

```
class Snippet < ApplicationRecord
  def self.run_blocks
    where(active: true).each do |snip|
     eval(snip.code_block)
    end
  end
end
```

this returns:

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `is_ten?' for #<Class:0x007fd11ba2bec8>
```

however if I do this in console, it works perfectly. Anybody have an idea on how to deal with this?

Comment: This is not a good thing to do in production code.

Comment: Fully aware @MarkThomas! This is for learning, not for production

Comment: I get that you're trying to learn, but at the same time, this is like learning how to stab knives into your eyes. It's not a very useful skill. What would be better is learning how to wrap code like this into a `module` you can load in on demand, do metaprogramming in Ruby properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `eval(snip.code_block`, you should try:

```
snip.instance_eval(code_block)
```

Hopefully that will work out of the box, but if it doesn't you may have to experiment with [`define_method`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method).

The reason why your code snippet doesn't work well with `eval` is that 1) Ruby doesn't support nested methods, and 2) you're trying to call an instance method from a class method. On the other hand, if your code looked like:

```
def self.is_ten?(number)
...
```

You might have better luck, but you'll still probably run into the first issue.

And as [@Mark Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182590/mark-thomas) observed, this is a very bad idea for production code (or, really, any code in general). Even if it's not intended for production use, chances are that [whatever problem you're trying to looking to solve with this question isn't actually the *real* problem you're looking to solve.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/369007)